# Can I lock my PS4 console from somewhere else?

Tags: ps4

I left my PS4 at someone's house and am unable to get it back.

Is there any way I could completely lock it down from my house on my other PS4 or computer? My PlayStation information and account is still on that PS4 as well as my new one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could remotely lock or logout your PS4 console. As doing so would be directly result in Hack attempt. But you could try changing your PSN password which is used on store.playstation.com. That would log out the user from the console and he would require either the new password to login or would need to create a new account.

However he would still be able to play games with his new account after logging into that console.

Answer (score 0):

You say you already have a second PS4, so what you'll want to do is make that one primary by going to `Settings->PlayStation network/Account Management->Activate as Your Primary PS4`

Then as the other answer states, you should immediately change your password.

This unfortunately won't remove your information, but it will mean that they can't access the information and will be unable to use anything you purchased.

Unfortunately, there's no way to force removal of the account.

You should also use two-step-verification, if you haven't already, to protect the account.